# why this errors in android studio occurred when i create new project?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> IDE Fatal Errors:

Exception in plugin **Android Support**. 3 minutes ago. occurred once since the last clear. Unread. Disable Plugin...

> Error Message:

```
Parse exception while reading distributions.json: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Details:
Parse exception while reading distributions.json: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:822)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.DistributionService.loadDistributionsFromJson(DistributionService.java:319)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.DistributionService.loadFromFile(DistributionService.java:297)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.DistributionService.loadStatsSynchronously(DistributionService.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.DistributionService.access$000(DistributionService.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.DistributionService$2.run(DistributionService.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open Android Studio Terminal type **gradlew**

   `C:\ProjectDir> gradlew`

   If error use this command: (Use proxy)

   `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580`
2. Set JDK location last version : File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK location

[image]